# Average value for each user from pivot table (dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted the table below from a csv file :

```
timestamp    user_id main_val  val1 val2    val3  transport
01/01/2011  1   1   3   1491    0   bus
01/07/2012  1   19  57  4867    5   bus
01/09/2013  1   21  63  3455    5   bus
01/02/2011  2   20  8   2121    5   bus
01/12/2012  2   240 30  3558    3   bus
01/01/2011  3   100 5   3357    3   bus
01/11/2012  3   3100    49  1830        bus
01/12/2013  3   3200    51  4637    4   bus
```

For this purpose I used the following statement:

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['date','user_id', 'cost', 'val1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False)

pivoted = df.pivot('date','user_id')
```

and now I have the dataframe pivoted containing the table below :

```
           cost    cost    cost  val1    val1   val1
user_id         1   2   3   1   2   3
timestamp                       
01/01/2011  1       100 3       5
01/02/2011      20          8   
01/07/2012  19          57      
01/09/2013  21          63      
01/11/2012          3100            49
01/12/2012      240         30  
01/12/2013          3200            51
```

**How can I now calculate a monthly average cost and val1 for each user_id?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the resample method
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

newnames = ['date','user_id', 'cost', 'val1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
pivoted = df.pivot('date','user_id')
pivoted.resample('M')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work : I receive the error message 'Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex'.

Comment: you can convert your timestamp column to datetime type before using the pivot table. See edit

Comment: Can you please explain. Do you mean something like :import pandas as
newnames = ['date','user_id', 'cost', 'val1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, header = False)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)

pivoted = df.pivot('date','user_id')

Comment: When I used this I obtain an additional row as index and white dates 1970-01-01 00:00:00 , 1970-01-01 00:00:01, 1970-01-01 00:00:02, etc

Comment: At 'df.timestamp = df.timestamp.astype(np.datetime64)' I receive the error message : 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timestamp'.

Comment: try with df['timestamp'] instead, or whatever the name of the column containing your dates

Comment: Now I have the error message : 'cannot create a Numpy datetime other than NaT with generic units' using df['date'] = df['date'].astype(np.datetime64)

Comment: I have replaced df['date'] = df['date'].astype(np.datetime64) by df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) and it seems working fine (dates are however presented as YYYY-MM-DD intead of DD-MM-YYYY).

Comment: I had forgotten about that to_datetime function, it's probably the way to go indeed :)
I have updated my code, you can consider accepting the answer if it worked.

Comment: pivoted.resample('M') does not give the average but sum of the value the month.